# How to load image files, each into their own canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, filereader, drawimage

I tried to load images into several canvas elements, but only the last image was loaded from the list of files. I need different images in different canvas elements, each in its own. Thanks for help.

HTML

```
<input type='file' id='imgfile' multiple />
```

The canvas element will be created by jQuery.

JavaScript

```
function loadImage(picture) {
  var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
  var input, fr, file, img;
  input = document.getElementById('imgfile');

  $.each(canvas, function(i, v) {
    file = input.files[i];
    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function createImage() {
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function imageLoaded() {
        var ctx = canvas[i].getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);
      }
      img.src = fr.result;
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}

$("input").change(function() {
  var picture = this.files;
  var leng = picture.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
    $("input").after('<canvas width="50" height="50" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>');
  }
  loadImage();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare variables inside iteratee function

```
function loadImage(picture) {
    var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
    var input = document.getElementById('imgfile');

    $.each( canvas, function( i, v) {
        var file = input.files[i]; 
        var fr = new FileReader(); // file reader per file
        fr.onload = function createImage() {
          var img = new Image(); // image per file
          img.onload = function imageLoaded() {
              var ctx = canvas[i].getContext("2d");
              ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, 50, 50);
          }
          img.src = fr.result;
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: That are working. Thank you for help. Why important that  declare variables inside iteratee ?

Comment: @Makhnov Simply because you want to have separate image for each file. Both `onload` events are async. By the time the first file got loaded the loop is already finished. That's why only the last image got rendered.

Comment: Loading files outside loop and reading files inside loop have been starting same time. Loop ended earlier than loading every pictures. Loop ended while when have been loaded first image.
How loop know about last image that put( drawImage ) in canvas ?